# How to import Vanilla JS ES6 modules in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, es6-modules

I'm trying to import this library: [spotlight](https://github.com/nextapps-de/spotlight), which is plain JS.

In my project I created a fake *d.ts*:

```
declare module 'spotlight.js'
```

as suggested by *VSCode*, then I tried every single import combination:

```
import * as spotlight from 'spotlight';
import spotlight from 'spotlight';
import { spotlight } from 'spotlight';
```

but inside my code the `spotlight` expression is always an empty object.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Shinigami pointed out - there is an open issue. As I see it, right now, there is no elegant way to `import` the `Spotlight` object without modifications to the library (it also seems that `npm run build` doesn't help much). But, judging by the code, the `Spotlight` is accessible through `window`. So it should be possible to use it like so

```js
import "spotlight"
window.Spotlight.show(...)
```

Comment: Interesting. Do you know if we can omit `{} from` and just use `import "spotlight"`?

Comment: @Shinigami, yes we can. Fixed it.

Answer (score 3):

There is an open issue for that: https://github.com/nextapps-de/spotlight/issues/6

Answer (score 0):

The declare statement has to be in a separate file initially, also make sure that you provided the right path for import statement.