# How to import vanilla JavaScript objects in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a traditional JavaScript file, say `abc.js` that does something like this:

```js
// abc.js
if (typeof ABC !== "object") {
    ABC = {};
}
(function () {
   // ... construct the ABC object
})
```

This is a 3rd-party dependency that I cannot touch.

Then, in my TypeScript file, say `main.ts`, I want to include the `ABC` object defined in `abc.js` so that the TypeScript checker can understand it.

Ideally I would like to end up with a single `.js` file after the compilation. What's the correct way of doing it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Call a global variable inside module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13252225/call-a-global-variable-inside-module)

Answer (score 0):

You can access to the JavaScript Object through `window`
For example:
import "spotlight"
window.Spotlight.show(...)
[How to import Vanilla JS ES6 modules in TypeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60242845/how-to-import-vanilla-js-es6-modules-in-typescript)

Answer (score 0):

You might need to tweak `tsconfig.json`

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowJs": true,
    "checkJs": false,
  }
}
```

and import in `main.ts`:

```
import * as ABC from './abc';
```